# How to add event handler to html tag in asp.net code behind?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, server-side

I have this html.

```
<a id="a1" runat=server>
```

I want to add event handler to this `<a>` tag using code behind. 
If a user press this tag, it should cause an event on the server-side.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what are you going to accomplish?

Answer (score 5):

For an easy solution there is the linkbutton on the toolbox which shows as a link but reacts as a button.

Comment: Or you could use Webmethods or callbacks but you need to express what exactly you want

Comment: With the linkbutton you get a postback which implies a trip to the server; what do you intend to gain from using a "onserverclick" that you can't get with the simple event handler that comes with the linkbutton?

Comment: ok let me explain more-I am getting an id of product on server side,now I want this linkbutton to send  his event handler the id of the product as a parameter (to the function),in simple event handler  I don't know The id yet

Comment: maybee something like:a1.attribute.add("onseverclick",function(id))

Comment: But where will the ID come from? If you will assemble the link beforehand wouldn't it be easier to put the validation on the "Page_Load"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5351/discussion-between-jclozano-and-baaroz)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it seems that you want something like this:

On the .ASPX page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myLinkButton" OnClick="myLinkButton_Click" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

In the .ASPX.CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLinkButton.CommandArgument = "1";
    }

    protected void myLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int myLinkButtonID = Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**Html Tag:**

```
<a id="a1" runat="server">
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      a1.ServerClick += new EventHandler(a1_ServerClick);
}

 protected void a1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Your Code here....
 }
```

This will Create a **Click Event** for the `<a>` tag.